# klogd, dmesg and syslog(2)

Tags: logs, rsyslog, syslog, dmesg

I got quite confused reading manual pages of `klogd`, `dmesg` and `syslog(2)`. I would like to understand how the message produced by the kernel gets to `/var/log/file`.

First thing I would like to get to know is whether or not `syslog(2)` is the same as system call `sys_syslog`.
As far as I know the kernel sends it's message to the kernel ring buffer using the `printk()` function. The messages are then available at `/proc/kmsg` and `/dev/kmsg` and I find it hard to understand how do `klogd`, `dmesg` and `sys_syslog(2)` get content from there.